# Updating the forms in react js doesn't keep track of the state of all the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-forms

I am facing issues while updating the values. Initially I am taking the values from the parent class to put into the text box, and then if I want to update the values into the form through the child component it should basically set the state in child component and pass the updated values to the API. But now when I try to change the values in the text box, it only changes one character and doesn't keep track of the state of all the props. How can I solve this? I have tried using the defaultValue it does change the values but it cannot keep track of the state change.

PS: The updateToApi is just a sample function that is using post to update values into the api
my sample project is here
 https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-perlman-ukb68?file=/src/parent.js

```
#class Parent#

    import React from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    import Child from "./child";

    class Parent extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          data: {
            username: ["mar"],
            name: [null]
          }
        };
      }
      updateToApi(data) {
        var username: data.username;
        var name: data.name;
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Child data={this.state.data} updateToApi={this.updateToApi.bind(this)} />
        );
      }
    }
    export default Parent;


##class Child##
    import React from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

    class Child extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          username: "",
          name: ""
        };
      }

      handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
      };

      handleChange = e => {
        const data = { ...this.state };
        data[e.currentTarget.name] = e.currentTarget.value;
        this.setState({ data });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <label>
                Username:
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="username"
                  value={
                    this.props.data.username !== "undefined"
                      ? this.props.data.username
                      : this.state.username
                  }
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </label>
              <b />

              <label>
                Name:
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="Name"
                  value={
                    this.props.data.name !== "undefined"
                      ? this.props.data.name
                      : this.state.name
                  }
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </label>
              <br />
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.props.updateToApi} />
            </form>
          </>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Child;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 2 separate states? You should get rid of the state in your Child component entirely and only work with the Parent's state. Put HandleChange function in your Parent component also and pass it down through props.

UPD

Well, if you want for changes in your inputs to be visible, you could change the onchange handler in your Child coponent to

```
handleChange = e => {
this.setState({
  [e.currentTarget.name] : e.currentTarget.value });
```

};

and the Input value just to `this.state.username`

Though i'm still having hard time to grasp what you are trying to accomplish here. Having 2 separate conditional states for the input fields is just too complicated. Imagine if your app would be a bit more complex? You'd lost yourself to debugging this stuff:

```
value={ this.props.data.username !== "undefined"
              ? this.state.username
              : this.state.username
          }
```

So here i highly recommend you to reevaluate all your data strucuture and data flow within the app. You should have the least amount of sources of truth within your app. Ideally one. So just use the main state in the Parent component and pass down the props that are required.

Comment: This is basically a sample. I am using the values in child to add new values in forms or edit values in forms in the real application. The parent component basically has the values that I get from the API.

Comment: @deathstranding I have updated my answer, please chec.